# Inline chapters' names in page header

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Probably not a very precise title for a question but I couldn't figure out a better one... Let me explain.

I have a document with a number of chapters in it (their names are defined by "Heading 1" style), and I want to make a header for each page with current chapter name styled the same way.

E.g.:

```
Chapter 1 <- title of chapter 1 added by me
text
Chapter 2 <- title of chapter 2 added by me
text
-- page break here --
Chapter 2 <- this is inserted automatically
more text
Chapter 3 <- title of Chapter 3 added by me
text
-- page break here --
Chapter 4 <- title of Chapter 4 added by me
```

I can add a header, insert "Chapter name" field there and add same style to it, and it will be sort of what I want, except for cases when chapter starts a page (that'd be Chapter 1 and Chapter 4 in the example). In those cases there will be duplicated chapter name - one from page header and then one from chapter heading.

It doesn't have to be chapters; I'm gladly accept almost any way to get this behaviour however hackish it might be.

Answer (score 0):

I have got Chapter (and sub-chapter) names showing in the footer and I thought I would share (headers work exactly the same, of course)

Sample page with Chapters and subheads in footer:

[image: Sample page with Chapters and subheads in Footer]

Note automatic (field) text is shaded gray ("Title goes here" should be gray too), and items related to optional chapter-numbering are highlighted in yellow.

Note, you must format your chapter names with a style which has an Outline level, as defined in Paragraph Style. In my case, *Heading 3* (which has Outline level 1) defines chapter names and *Heading 5* (which has Outline level 2) defines "sub-chapters" or sections.

Then,

- *Tools*, *Chapter Numbering*;
- *Level* defines chapter names & numbers at multiple levels; start with Level 1
- set *Paragraph Style* to the style you are using for the the chapter name
  (*Heading 3* in my case for Level 1)
- set *Number* (Style) as desired (if showing numbers; else ignore)
- All other options may be left at default; they are explained [in this help item](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Inserting_a_Chapter_Name_and_Number_in_a_Header_or_a_Footer).

Then, to show chapter names, insert a *Chapter* field in your header or footer:

- Click in header/footer: *Insert*, *Field*, *More Fields*
- *Type* = *Chapter*
- *Format* = as desired: chapter name, number or name+number.
- *Level* = 1

To show "sub-chapters," go back to *Tools*, *Chapter Numbering*, select *Level* 2 and fill in the options, using a different Outline level. Then go back to your header/footer, add another *Chapter* field, set *Level* = 2

Note *Chapter Numbering* levels have nothing to do with *Heading* levels; they seem to link to Outline levels. I am not sure. But if I edit another Paragraph style to give it Outline level 1 or 2, the text from paragraphs in that style appear in the footer!